# What is the meaning of "this" in Java?

Tags: java, this

Normally, I use `this` in constructors only.

I understand that it is used to identify the parameter variable (by using `this.something`), if it have a same name with a global variable.

However, I don't know that what the real meaning of `this` is in Java and what will happen if I use `this` without dot (`.`).

Comment: To the answerers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15775/do-you-delete-your-own-answer-when-its-a-duplicate

Comment: Yakshemash ! SO friends. You might want to refer to my question here as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23334336/this-in-java-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-stackoverflowerror Chenqui.

Comment: There are no global variables in Java.

Answer (score 170):

`this` refers to the current object.

Each non-static method runs in the context of an object. So if you have a class like this:

```
public class MyThisTest {
  private int a;

  public MyThisTest() {
    this(42); // calls the other constructor
  }

  public MyThisTest(int a) {
    this.a = a; // assigns the value of the parameter a to the field of the same name
  }

  public void frobnicate() {
    int a = 1;

    System.out.println(a); // refers to the local variable a
    System.out.println(this.a); // refers to the field a
    System.out.println(this); // refers to this entire object
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "MyThisTest a=" + a; // refers to the field a
  }
}
```

Then calling `frobnicate()` on `new MyThisTest()` will print

```
1
42
MyThisTest a=42
```

So effectively you use it for multiple things:

- clarify that you are talking about a field, when there's also something else with the same name as a field
- refer to the current object as a whole
- invoke other constructors of the current class in your constructor

Comment: This isn't working.  I get an error saying that a `main` method is required.  If i add the main method, then I have to call from there.  And any attempt to call frobnicate() inside main says that you can't call a non-static reference from inside a static one. And removing static from `main` returns the error again that no main method i s found.  Please explain.

Comment: @dbconfession: the code here is not meant as a stand-alone, self-running program. You're meant to *read* the *code* **and** the text, not run it! It is valid code, but it's only meant for demonstration purposes (that's why it doesn't have a proper main). For help with the main method, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146576/why-is-the-java-main-method-static.

Comment: @Joachim Thanks! I'm missing something fundamental about what it means to make a method static and how `this.` works.  My understanding is that `this.` allows you to call a method or variable that is unique to the instantiated version of the class, allowing for another version of the method or variable to exist which is called without invoking `this.`  In a simple called `Test.class` I have two methods: `public static void main()` and `public Test()`  I can't pass information between the methods because `main` is static and constructors can't be made static. Should I post as a new question?

Comment: @dbconfession: I have a feeling your question is already answered elsewhere, but I don't quite grasp what exactly your question is, so you might as well post it (but be prepared to have it closed as a duplicate). However, on the most fundamental level, making a method `static` basically means that you don't need an instance of the class to call it and that you won't have access to `this` inside it.

Comment: @JoachimSauer If I wanted to run it, how would I? I've got the same problem as dbconfession.

Comment: I don't understand where in the code triggers the class `toString()`, does `System.out.println(this);` call every single method within the class?... (I tried creating other methods and they don't get automatically called)

Comment: @nsv0000: `println` has several overloads. If you call it with an object that doesn't match any of the others, [the `println(Object)` version](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)) will be called. That one is specified to call `toString()` (via `String.valueOf()`). on the parameter (if it's not `null`). That's a common theme: when Java wants a string representation of an object and nothing else is specifies, it'll usually call `toString()` on the object.

Answer (score 55):

The following is a copy & paste from [here](http://javapapers.com/core-java/explain-the-java-this-keyword/), but explains very well all different uses of the `this` keyword:

Definition: **Java’s `this` keyword is used to refer the current instance of the method on which it is used.**

Following are the ways to use this:

1. To specifically denote that the instance variable is used instead of static or local variable. That is,

   ```
   private String javaFAQ;
   void methodName(String javaFAQ) {
       this.javaFAQ = javaFAQ;
   }
   ```

   Here this refers to the instance variable. Here the precedence is high for the local variable. Therefore the absence of the `this` denotes the local variable. If the local variable that is parameter’s name is not same as instance variable then irrespective of `this` is used or not it denotes the instance variable.
2. `this` is used to refer the constructors

   ```
    public JavaQuestions(String javapapers) {
        this(javapapers, true);
    }
   ```

   This invokes the constructor of the same java class which has two parameters.
3. `this` is used to pass the current java instance as parameter

   ```
   obj.itIsMe(this);
   ```
4. Similar to the above this can also be used to return the current instance

   ```
   CurrentClassName startMethod() {
        return this;
   }
   ```

   Note: This may lead to undesired results while used in inner classes in the above two points. Since this will refer to the inner class and not the outer instance.
5. `this` can be used to get the handle of the current class

   ```
   Class className = this.getClass(); // this methodology is preferable in java
   ```

Though this can be done by

```
    Class className = ABC.class; // here ABC refers to the class name and you need to know that!
```

As always, `this` is associated with its instance and this will not work in static methods.

Answer (score 48):

To be complete, `this` can also be used to refer to the outer object

```
class Outer {
    class Inner {
        void foo() {
            Outer o = Outer.this;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `this` is what I was looking for! ;)

Comment: That's just `super`

Answer (score 21):

It refers to the current instance of a particular object, so you could write something like

```
public Object getMe() {
    return this;
}
```

---

A common use-case of `this` is to prevent shadowing. Take the following example:

```
public class Person {
    private final String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        // how would we initialize the field using parameter?
        // we can't do: name = name;
    }
}
```

In the above example, we want to assign the field member using the parameter's value. Since they share the same name, we need a way to distinguish between the field and the parameter. `this` allows us to access members of this instance, including the field.

```
public class Person {
    private final String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful to use proper style when calling it: o.getMe().getMe().outOfHere()

Answer (score 9):

Quoting an [article](https://programming.guide/java/this.html) at programming.guide:

---

`this` has **two uses** in a Java program.

### 1. As a reference to the current object

The syntax in this case usually looks something like

```
this.someVariable = someVariable;
```

This type of use is described here: [The 'this' reference (with examples)](https://programming.guide/java/this-reference-with-examples.html)

### 2. To call a different constructor

The syntax in this case typically looks something like

```
MyClass() {
    this(DEFAULT_VALUE); // delegate to other constructor
}

MyClass(int value) {
    // ...
}
```

This type of use is described here: [this(…) constructor call (with examples)](https://programming.guide/java/this-constructor-call-with-examples.html)

Answer (score 8):

In Swing its fairly common to write a class that implements `ActionListener` and add the current instance (ie 'this') as an ActionListener for components.

```
public class MyDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener
{
    public MyDialog()
    {
        JButton myButton = new JButton("Hello");
        myButton.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        System.out.println("Hurdy Gurdy!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's "a reference to the object in the current context" effectively. For example, to print out "this object" you might write:

```
System.out.println(this);
```

Note that your usage of "global variable" is somewhat off... if you're using `this.variableName` then by definition it's *not* a global variable - it's a variable specific to this particular instance.

Answer (score 6):

It refers to the instance on which the method is called

```
class A {

  public boolean is(Object o) {
    return o == this;
  }

}

A someA = new A();
A anotherA = new A();
someA.is(someA); // returns true
someA.is(anotherA); // returns false
```

Answer (score 4):

The **this** Keyword is used to refer the current variable of a block, for example consider the below code(Just a exampple, so dont expect the standard JAVA Code):

```
Public class test{

test(int a) {
this.a=a;
}

Void print(){
System.out.println(a);
}

   Public static void main(String args[]){
    test s=new test(2);
    s.print();
 }
}
```

Thats it. the Output will be "2".
If We not used the **this** keyword, then the output will be : 0

Answer (score 3):

Objects have methods and attributes(variables) which are derived from classes, in order to specify which methods and variables belong to a particular object the `this` reserved word is used. in the case of instance variables, it is important to understand the difference between implicit and explicit parameters. Take a look at the `fillTank` call for the `audi` object.

```
Car audi= new Car();

audi.fillTank(5); // 5 is the explicit parameter and the car object is the implicit parameter
```

The value in the parenthesis is the implicit parameter and the object itself is the explicit parameter, methods that don't have explicit parameters, use implicit parameters, the `fillTank` method has both an explicit and an implicit parameter.

Lets take a closer look at the `fillTank` method in the `Car` class

```
public class Car()
{
   private double tank;

   public Car()
   {
      tank = 0;
   }

   public void fillTank(double gallons)
   {
      tank = tank + gallons;
   }

}
```

In this class we have an instance variable "tank". There could be many objects that use the tank instance variable, in order to specify that the instance variable "tank" is used for a particular object, in our case the "audi" object we constructed earlier, we use the `this` reserved keyword. for **instance variables** the use of 'this' in a **method** indicates that the instance variable, in our case "tank", is instance variable of the implicit parameter.

The java compiler automatically adds the `this` reserved word so you don't have to add it, it's a matter of preference. You can not use `this` without a dot(.) because those are the rules of java ( the syntax).

In summary.

- Objects are defined by classes and have methods and variables
- The use of `this` on an **instance variable** in a **method** indicates that, the instance variable belongs to the implicit parameter, or that it is an instance variable of the implicit parameter.
- The implicit parameter is the object the method is called from in this case "audi".
- The java compiler automatically adds the this reserved word, adding it is a matter of preference
- `this` cannot be used without a dot(.) this is syntactically invalid
- `this` can also be used to distinguish between local variables and global variables that have the same name
- the `this` reserve word also applies to methods, to indicate a method belongs to a particular object.

Answer (score 2):

Instance variables are common to every object that you creating. say, there is two instance variables

```
class ExpThisKeyWord{
int x;
int y;

public void setMyInstanceValues(int a, int b) {
    x= a;
    y=b;

    System.out.println("x is ="+x);
    System.out.println("y is ="+y);
}

}




class Demo{
public static void main(String[] args){

ExpThisKeyWord obj1 = new ExpThisKeyWord();
ExpThisKeyWord obj2 = new ExpThisKeyWord();
ExpThisKeyWord obj3 = new ExpThisKeyWord();

obj1.setMyInstanceValues(1, 2);
obj2.setMyInstanceValues(11, 22);
obj3.setMyInstanceValues(111, 222);



}
}
```

if you noticed above code, we have initiated three objects and three objects are calling SetMyInstanceValues method.
 How do you think JVM correctly assign the values for every object?
 there is the trick, JVM will not see this code how it is showed above. instead of that, it will see like below code;

```
public void setMyInstanceValues(int a, int b) {
    this.x= a; //Answer: this keyword denotes the current object that is handled by JVM.
    this.y=b;

    System.out.println("x is ="+x);
    System.out.println("y is ="+y);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*(I know Im late but shh Im being the sneaky boi you never saw me)*

The  **this** keyword in most Object Oriented programming languages if not all means that its a reference towards the current object instance of that class. It's essentially the same thing as calling on that object from outside of the method by name. That probably made no sense so Ill elaborate:

Outside of the class, in order to call something within that instance of the object, for example a say you have an object called object and you want to get a field you would need to use

```
object.field
```

Say for instance you are trying to access **object.field** from inside of your class in say, your constructor for example, you could use

```
this.field
```

The **this** keyword essentially replaces the object name keyword when being called inside of the class. There usually isn't much of a reason to do this outside of if you have two variables of the same name one of which being a field of the class and the other just being a variable inside of a method, it helps decipher between the two. For example if you have this: 
(Hah, get it? *this*? Hehe .... just me? okay :(  I'll leave now)

```
public String Name;
//Constructor for {object} class
public object(String Name){
    Name = Name;
}
```

That would cause some problems, the compiler wouldn't be able to know the difference between the Name variable defined in the parameters for the constructor and the Name variable inside of your class' field declarations so it would instead assign the Name parameter to.... the value of the Name parameter which does nothing beneficial and literally has no purpose. This is a common issue that most newer programs do and I was a victim of as well. Anyways, the correct way to define this parameter would be to use:

```
public String Name;
//Constructor for {object} class
public object(String Name){
    this.Name = Name;
}
```

This way, the compiler knows the Name variable you are trying to assign is a part of the class and not a part of the method and assigns it correctly, meaning it assigns the Name field to whatever you put into the constructor.

To sum it up, it essentially references a field of the object instance of the class you are working on, hence it being the keyword "this", meaning its *this* object, or *this* instance. Its a good practice to use this when calling a field of your class rather than just using the name to avoid possible bugs that are difficult to find as the compiler runs right over them.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search brought this result: [Link](http://xahlee.info/java-a-day/this.html)

Pretty much the "this" keyword is a reference to the current object (itself).

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a reference to the current object: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Answer (score 1):

this can be used inside some method or constructor.

It returns the reference to the current object.

Answer (score 1):

This refers to the object you’re “in” right now. In other words,this refers to the receiving object. You use this to clarify which variable you’re referring to.[Java_whitepaper page :37](http://www.stroustrup.com/1995_Java_whitepaper.pdf)

```
class Point extends Object
{
    public double x;
    public double y;

    Point()
    {
        x = 0.0;
        y = 0.0;
    }

    Point(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

In the above example code this.x/this.y refers to current class that is Point class x and y variables where 
(double x,double y) are double values passed from different class to assign values to current class .

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for the same answer, and somehow couldn't understand the concept clearly. But finally I understood it from this [link](http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/core-java-tutorial/this-keyword-in-java/)

this  is a keyword in Java. Which can be used inside method or constructor of  class. It(this) works as a reference to a current object whose method or constructor is being invoked. this keyword can be used to refer any member of current object from within an instance method or a constructor.

Check the examples in the [link](http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/core-java-tutorial/this-keyword-in-java/) for a clear understanding

Comment: perfect example

Answer (score 0):

If the instance variables are same as the variables that are declared in the constructor then we use "this" to assign data.

```
class Example{
     int assign;// instance variable

     Example(int assign){ // variable inside constructor
          this.assign=assign;
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Java "this" is a predefined variable. If we use "this" in method that's mean we are getting the reference (address) of the currently running object. For an example.

this.age ---> age of the currently running object.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share what I understood from this keyword.
This keyword has 6 usages in java as follows:-

**1. It can be used to refer to the current class variable.**
 Let us understand with a code.*

Let's understand the problem if we don't use this keyword by the example given below:

```
class Employee{  
int id_no;  
String name;  
float salary;  
Student(int id_no,String name,float salary){  
id_no = id_no;  
name=name;  
salary = salary;  
}  
void display(){System.out.println(id_no +" "+name+" "+ salary);}  
}  
class TestThis1{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
Employee s1=new Employee(111,"ankit",5000f);  
Employee s2=new Employee(112,"sumit",6000f);  
s1.display();  
s2.display();  
}}
```

Output:-

```
0 null 0.0
0 null 0.0
```

In the above example, parameters (formal arguments) and instance variables are same. So, we are using this keyword to distinguish local variable and instance variable.

```
class Employee{  
int id_no;  
String name;  
float salary;  
Student(int id_no,String name,float salary){  
this.id_no = id_no;  
this.name=name;  
this.salary = salary;  
}  
void display(){System.out.println(id_no +" "+name+" "+ salary);}  
}  
class TestThis1{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
Employee s1=new Employee(111,"ankit",5000f);  
Employee s2=new Employee(112,"sumit",6000f);  
s1.display();  
s2.display();  
}}
```

output:

```
111 ankit 5000
112 sumit 6000
```

**2. To invoke the current class method.**

```
class A{  
void m(){System.out.println("hello Mandy");}  
void n(){  
System.out.println("hello Natasha");  
//m();//same as this.m()  
this.m();  
}  
}  
class TestThis4{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
A a=new A();  
a.n();  
}}
```

Output:

```
hello Natasha
hello Mandy
```

**3. to invoke the current class constructor. It is used to constructor chaining.**

```
class A{  
A(){System.out.println("hello ABCD");}  
A(int x){  
this();  
System.out.println(x);  
}  
}  
class TestThis5{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
A a=new A(10);  
}}
```

Output:

```
hello ABCD
10
```

**4. to pass as an argument in the method.**

```
class S2{  
  void m(S2 obj){  
  System.out.println("The method is invoked");  
  }  
  void p(){  
  m(this);  
  }  
  public static void main(String args[]){  
  S2 s1 = new S2();  
  s1.p();  
  }  
}
```

Output:

```
The method is invoked
```

**5. to pass as an argument in the constructor call**

```
class B{  
  A4 obj;  
  B(A4 obj){  
    this.obj=obj;  
  }  
  void display(){  
    System.out.println(obj.data);//using data member of A4 class  
  }  
}  

class A4{  
  int data=10;  
  A4(){  
   B b=new B(this);  
   b.display();  
  }  
  public static void main(String args[]){  
   A4 a=new A4();  
  }  
}
```

Output:-

```
10
```

**6. to return current class instance**

```
class A{  
A getA(){  
return this;  
}  
void msg(){System.out.println("Hello");}  
}  
class Test1{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
new A().getA().msg();  
}  
}
```

Output:-

```
Hello
```

> Also, this keyword cannot be used without .(dot) as it's syntax is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone said, this represents the current object / current instance. I understand it this way,
if its just "this" - it returns class object, in below ex: Dog
if it has this.something, something is a method in that class or a variable

```
class Dog {
private String breed;
private String name;

Dog(String breed, String name) {
    this.breed = breed;
    this.name = name;
}

public Dog getDog() {
    // return Dog type
    return this;
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The expression `this` always refers to the current instance.

- In case of constructors, the current instance is the freshly allocated object that's currently being constructed.
- In case of methods, the current instance is the instance on which you have called the method.

So, if you have a class `C` with some method `m`, then

- during the construction of a fresh instance `x` of `C`, the `this` inside of the constructor will refer to `x`.
- When `x` is an instance of `C`, and you invoke `x.m()`, then within the body of `m`, `this` will refer to the instance `x`.

Here is a code snippet that demonstrates both cases:

```
public class Example {
    static class C {
        public C whatDoesThisInConstructorReferTo;
        public C() {
            whatDoesThisInConstructorReferTo = this;
        }
        public C whatDoesThisInMethodReferTo() {
            return this;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      C x = new C();
      System.out.println(x.whatDoesThisInConstructorReferTo == x); // true
      System.out.println(x.whatDoesThisInMethodReferTo() == x);    // true
    }
}
```

Regarding other syntactical elements that are unrelated to the `this`-expression:

- The `.` is just the ordinary member access, it works in exactly the same way as in all other circumstances, nothing special is happening in case of `this`.
- The `this(...)` (with round parentheses) is a special syntax for constructor invocation, not a reference.

Comment: I know that the question is over seven hundred years old, but none of the other answers bothered to demonstrate explicitly what the `this` is referring to by the means of simple `==`-equations. I don't think that one needs so much prose to demonstrate that `A == B` for some `A` and `B`.