# What does it really mean by 'this' in java?

Tags: java

```
class A {

    void methodA {
        B b= new B();
        b.methodB();
        //point 1
    }

    private class B {
        void methodB(){
            //point 2
        }
    }
}
```

if I use a system out to print `this.toString()` at both point 1 and point 2, it gives the same value. Can anyone please tell me why ? Shouldn't those two give different values ?

Comment: `this` *always* refers to the object/instance the method was invoked upon. So at "point 1" `this` will evaluate to an instance of class A and at "point 2" `this` will be an instance of class B (in particular, the one created with `new B()` above). If `this.toString()` gives the same value then perhaps it "generates the same string"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of "this" in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java)

Comment: Your question title is misleading, given your further description. It's also hard to diagnose what your ***real*** problem is when you illustrate it with uncompilable code.

Answer (score 2):

They are different, try this:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A().methodA();
    }
}

class A {

    void methodA() {
        B b= new B();
        b.methodB();
        //point 1
        System.out.println(this.toString());
    }

    private class B {

        void methodB(){
            //point 2
            System.out.println(this.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> if I use a system out to print this.toString() at both point 1 and point 2, it gives the same value.

I am not agree with you.

`this` always refers to current object reference in java.

```
void methodA() {
    B b = new B();
    b.methodB();
    // point 1
    System.out.println(this.toString());
}

private class B {

    void methodB() {
        // point 2
        System.out.println(this.toString());
    }
}
```

Result -
Sample$B@9304b1
Sample@190d11

See from the inner class method it prints `Sample$B@9304b1` where Sample is base class and B is inner class and hashcode. Where class method it prints class name with `@` and hashcode.

**Both hashcode is different so both object is different**. so this refers different object instance.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that point 1 and point 2 print DIFFERENT things ... unless you've overloaded the `toString()` methods:

Your program:

```
class A {

    void methodA() {
        B b= new B();
        b.methodB();
        System.err.println("point 1 - " + this.toString());
    }

    private class B {
        void methodB(){
            System.err.println("point 2 - " + this.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A().methodA();
    }
}
```

Prints this when I run it.

```
point 2 - A$B@58c3d9ac
point 1 - A@2207d8bb
```

In fact, the output clearly tells us that `this` means different things at points 1 and 2.  At point 1, `this` refers to an instance of `A`.  At point 2, `this` refers to an instance of `A.B`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It's the behavior of the `toString()` method.You are accessing `this` keyword which refers to the current instance of the class.
as visal_aim posted answer in such case at **point1** `this` keyword will be referring to instance of Class A and at `point 2`  it will be referring to instance of class B.

You are getting same answer because at both the point `this` is type of `object` and that will return the same string. (Untill you have override the toString() method of base Object Class).