# Classes and its Objects

Tags: java, oop

```
public class A
{
    private void sub()
    {
        add();
    }

    private void add()
    { 
          -----
    }
}
```

I can call the add method in sub like above and I can do the same as below

```
public class A
{
    private void sub()
    {
        A obj_A = new A();
        obj_A.add();
    }
    private void add()
    { 
           -----
    }
}
```

I would like to know the differences between them.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first method you are calling the `add` method of the same instance of the class. In the second example you are creating a new instance of the class and calling its `add` method.

For example:

```
public class A
    {
        private int num = 3;

        private void sub()
        {
          num = 10;            
          add();
        }
        private void add()
        { 
              system.out.println(num);
        }
    }

public class A
{
    private int num = 3;

    private void sub()
    {
        A obj_A = new A();
        num = 10;      
        obj_A.add();
    }
    private void add()
    { 
           system.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

In the first example, it will print 10. In the second one, it will print 3. This os because in the first example you are printing num of the instance itself that you have previously modified. In the second example you also modify num value but since you are invoking add of the new class you have created it will print 3.

Comment: but in the second case if I assign num as 10 in the sub and then call add then num will be again 10.

Comment: @Raghurocks.. No num will not be 10 there. A different instance is running the `add()` method. And in `sub()` method, you are setting `num = 10`, for different instance.

Comment: @Raghurocks.. Currently it is - `this.num = 10;` To change num for new object, you need - `obj_A.num = 10;`.

Comment: @Raghurocks And what if num doesn't have public accessors? This should show roughly what is happening. You have two values of `num`, one on each instance of `class A`. In your second example you create a whole new instance of A.

Comment: @RohitJain you said 2 instances will be created in the second case, and 1 instance will be created in the 1st case, so when will an instance will be created? when we call a method?

Comment: @Raghurocks.. When you first time call `sub()` method from `main`, you are creating an instance of `A`, right. Now, in `sub()` method, you are again creating an instance of `A()`, to call `add()` method. Whereas in 1st case, you are invoking the `add()` method on the same reference `this`. `this` is a reference to the current instance executing. So, in first case, `this` refers to the same instance in both `add()` and `sub()` method. Whereas in 2nd case, `this` refers to different instances in both methods.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help , so I can confirm that when we call a method from main we are creating an instance of that class right?.Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 4):

- If you create an instance of A with the first class and invoke `sub()` you will have 1
  instance of A within the method scope.
- If you create an instance of A with the second class and invoke `sub()` you will have
  2 instances of A wihin the method scope.

Comment: This could confuse, as obj_A only has local scope, and will be released when the method sub completes.

Comment: @Xetius you are right. now the confusion is removed, i think.

Answer (score 2):

Java classes have a special member defined called [`this`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) which refers to the current object.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java) will give you more details on [`this`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
private void sub()
{
  add();
}
```

Calling method `add()` on the same object which called `sub()` method.

```
private void sub()
{
   A obj_A = new A();
   obj_A.add();
}
```

Creating new object of type A and calling `add()` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

By second method, to invoke add method two objects will be created, by using the method 1 we can access add method by just creating one object

Answer (score 0):

In second approch unneciserly we are creating Object.

First approch is better.