# Error trying to play sound OnItemClick

Tags: android, listview, media-player

I am trying to play sound `OnItemClick` from a `ListView` I have set up.

I'm getting the error "The method `create(Context, int)` in the type `MediaPlayer` is not applicable for the arguments (`new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, int)`" with "create" underlined.

Not 100% sure why I am getting this error, if somebody could help, would be much appreciated.

```
ListView BoardList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.BoardList);
BoardList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

String List[] = {"Play 1", "Play 2", "Play 3", "Play 4", "Play 5", "Play 6", "Play 7", "Play 8", "Play 9" };
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listcustomize, R.id.textItem, List);

BoardList.setAdapter(adapter);
BoardList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (position == 0) {
            MediaPlayer  mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.Audio1);
            mPlayer .start();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `this` inside your MediaPlayer object you should write `YourActivityName.this` and try again!

```
MediaPlayer  mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(YourActivityName.this, R.raw.Audio1);
```

This error occurs because you are inside the listener and the word `this` refers to the listener itself and not to your Activity.

Comment: Thank you good sir, you have taught somebody something today which will never be forgotten, Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could expand your answer a bit to include an explanation about scope. I am sure future readers struggling with the problem will find it useful!

Comment: It's actually not a scope problem, it's about the basics of programming because in languages like Java you have to understand when the word `this` refers to the object you want

Comment: And to understand when the keyword `this` and how to use it properly you should ideally have a good grasp on scope. In this case, scope refers to object scope. Here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java, are some explanations about `this` that can lead to a better understanding of object scope, Basically, when `this` was used in the `onItemClick` method, it was inside the scope of the `OnItemClickListener` object.