# Greenfoot, using "this"

Tags: java, greenfoot

I am just starting to use greenfoot and I am looking into some examples and find that people often use "this", what does it exactly mean, I don't really understand, for example:

```
//set the animal's age
public void setAge(int age)
{
   this.age = age;
}
```

Comment: Come on, just search for "this" in Google or SO.

Comment: I did, but I thought I would get a better explanation here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The `this` refers to the current instance of an object**. So, in your example:

```
public void setAge(int age)
{
   this.age = age;
}
```

The use of `this` in the `setAge` setter means we are referring to the instance variable `age` in the `this.age` and setting that equal to the value of the parameter `age`. This means `this.age` and `age` refer to different variables.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword

```
this
```

refers to an instance of the enclosing class. In your example, "this" will refer to the class containing that keyword.

You question might already have been answered here:

[What is the meaning of "this" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java)