# This in Java - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Why am I getting a stackoverflow error ?

**My class -**

```
public class Tester {

int id;

 Tester(int id){
  this.id = id;
 }

 public String toString(){

  String rep = "Hex: " + this + ", Id: " + this.id;
  return rep;
 }

}
```

**The main method -**

```
class Driver{

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Tester t = new Tester(123);
        System.out.println(t);

    }

}
```

**Error -**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.String.length(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.examscam.model.Tester.toString(Tester.java:13)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)

---------REPEAT !!!
```

Comment: What is ur intention to do in toString method

Comment: @VineetSingla - to show the value of `this`. But obviously, I can't do that without causing a SO error.

Comment: Printing this will just print the classname@hashcode values, Tester class has only one attribute id, so just printing the id should work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stack-overflow-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wrote:

```
String rep = "Hex: " + this + ", Id: " + this.id;
```

In java simply writing `this` means that you are indirectly invoking `this.toString()`.

I believe you are trying to override the `toString()` method of `Object` and inside your version of `toString()` you want to print the id you have passed along with the `hashcode` of the object.

So to get the output replace

```
String rep = "Hex: " + this + ", Id: " + this.id;
```

with

```
String rep = "Hex: "+ this.getClass().getName().hashCode() +", Id: " + id;
```

and you will get the output as:

```
Hex: 1800024669, Id: 123
```

Comment: Thank you Parul. Yes, the oracle docs toString() have a same definitions. Borat very much like your answer ! High five !

Comment: You can also just use `super.toString()` to call the super class method.

Answer (score 16):

Because

```
"Hex: " + this
```

is equivalent to

```
"Hex: " + this.toString()
```

and you're doing that from the `toString()`, so `toString()` calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself...

Answer (score 4):

you are using `this` keyword.

```
String rep = "Hex: " + this + ", Id: " + this.id;
```

This represent the current object. Your current object is being called again and again recursivley so you are getting

`java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Answer (score 4):

You are appending "this". This calls the toString() method, which again calls toString(), ...
It's an infinite recursion loop, which does not have an end.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are referencing `this` in toString()

That means that `this.toString()` is being called, therefor infinite recursion is occurring

Answer (score 2):

Your toString method is the culprit,

```
String rep = "Hex: " + super.toString() /* Not this */
   + ", Id: " + this.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

thi line

```
String rep = "Hex: " + this + ", Id: " + this.id;
```

would become

```
String rep = "Hex: " + this.toString() + ", Id: " + this.id;
```

at run-time and will again call your class's toString..wi again..

Answer (score 1):

In the  line  `String rep = "Hex: " + this + ", Id: " + this.id;`

```
  this
```

is equivalent to

```
 this.toString()
```

and calling it from the toString(), will again call toString and again...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overriding toString method and in your overrided method body your calling your method again! you are calling toString by writing this+"" in toString method

Answer (score 0):

```
String rep = "Hex: " + this + ", Id: " + this.id;
```

equal to      `String rep = "Hex: " + this.toString() + ", Id: " + this.id;` internally

this will leads to recursive method call that will result in

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Answer (score 0):

Because using first this in your toString method goes on calling the toString method recursively resulting in a stackoverflow.