# Method returns null [simple]

Tags: java, null, encapsulation, instance-variables

For introductory Java, I'm creating a Door class and a DoorTester class. Essentially, we're experimenting with instance variables and creating public methods. I've made the door class as follows, but my DoorTester returns "null" when it looks for .getState

Door.java

```
public class Door {
// Create instance variables of type String
private String name;
private String state;

// Declare method 'open' and 'close'
public void open() {
    state = "open";
}
public void close() {
    state = "closed";
}

// Add a constructor for the Door class
public Door(String name, String state) {
}

// Create an accessor of 'state'
public String getState() {
    return name;
}

// Set the state
public void setState(String newState) {
    state = newState;
}
```

}

DoorTester.java

```
public class DoorTester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Door frontDoor = new Door("Front", "open");
   System.out.println("The front door is " + frontDoor.getState());
   System.out.println("Expected:  open");
   Door backDoor = new Door("Back", "closed");
   System.out.println("Expected:  closed");        
   // Use the mutator to change the state variable
   backDoor.setState("open");
   System.out.println("The back door is " + backDoor.getState());
   System.out.println("Expected:  open");
   // Add code to test the setName mutator here 
  }
```

}

Comment: you don't set the private variables in your constructor.....

Comment: You never assigned your variables in your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to modify your constructor of `Door` class like

```
public Door(String name, String state) {
this.name=name;
this.state=state;
}
```

Actually `name` and `state` are not getting initialized.
Also see this ***[What is the meaning of "this" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java)***

---

**Modified Code Snippet:**

```
public class Door {
// Create instance variables of type String
private String name;
private String state;

// Declare method 'open' and 'close'
public void open() {
    state = "open";
}
public void close() {
    state = "closed";
}

// Add a constructor for the Door class
public Door(String name, String state) {
 this.name=name;
 this.state=state;
}

// Create an accessor of 'state'
public String getState() {
    return state;            //<<<<<<<----------also make an Edit here 
}

// Set the state
public void setState(String newState) {
    state = newState;
}
}
```

Comment: What does 'this' mean? - New to Java -

Comment: this means that you want to refer to the context of the enclosing class

Answer (score 0):

Your `getState()` method doesn't return `state`, it returns `name`:

```
// Create an accessor of 'state'
public String getState() {
    return name; // <-- Simply change this
}
```

Also, your constructor doesn't set the fields. You need to do something like this:

```
// Add a constructor for the Door class
public Door(String name, String state) {
    this.name = name;
    this.state = state;
}
```

Comment: I changed it to state and null still returns.

Comment: @mshades: That was only one of the two problems. You need to do both corrections I mention.

Comment: Thanks, both together fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are issues in your `Door` class

```
public class Door {
private String name;
private String state;

public void open() {
    state = "open";
}

public void close() {
    state = "closed";
}

public Door(String name, String state) { // argument passed here need to set
// set like
  this.name=name;
  this.state=state;
}

public String getState() {
    return name;
}

public void setState(String state) { 
    state = state; // you need to use this.state=state
 }
}
```

Importance of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) keyword in `Java`

Comment: No need to use `this.state` since the argument is named `newState`.

Comment: Is there a way I can do it without "this"? @Keppil

Comment: @mshades: Sure, just use different names for the field and the argument, e.g. `state` and `newState`.