# What is this Java method being called on?

Tags: java

Alright, so I am new to Java and  have a quick question for anyone who would be nice enough to answer it.

What object is this doSomething method called on? Is it the same as calling this.doSomething()?

```
public class Something{

    public void doSomething(){
         System.out.println("Something is done");
    }

    public Something(){
    //what object is this being called on?
       doSomething();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Something foo = new Something();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: yes. check more details on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java

Answer (score 0):

> what object is this being called on?

The reference which is going to be assigned to `foo`, in the scope of the constructor it is the **`this`** *reference*. And yes, `doSomething();` (in this *context*) is equivalent to `this.doSomething();`

We can see this is the case by adding a `UUID` to `Something` (and displaying it in `doSomething`),

```
public Something() {
    uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    doSomething();
}
private final String uuid;
public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println(uuid);
}
```

and then calling `doSomething()` *again* in `main` like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Something foo = new Something();
    foo.doSomething();
}
```

And you'll get the same UUID twice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `doSomething` is defined within the Something class. Therefore, that is the same as `this.doSomething()`.

To call the `doSomething()` (declared within "`Something`" class) from outside the class, you would need to call it like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Something foo = new Something();
    foo.doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Calling this.doSomething is same as calling doSomething(). Not sure what GUI are using. For example if you use Eclipse and have the below code and you click on doSomething it will take you to the void doSomething method. using this is just a reference to the current instance. More details can be found regarding this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

```
public class Something{

    public void doSomething(){
         System.out.println("Something is done");
    }

    public Something(){
    //what object is this being called on?
       this.doSomething();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Something foo = new Something();
    }
}
```