# using "this.field = value" vs "field = value"

Tags: java

I know what `this` does and why it's useful - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java) question did a great job of explaining it. However, in the chosen answer they used `this` to also assign parameters. Does doing

```
private int aNumber;

public void assignVal(int aNumber){
    this.aNumber = aNumber;
}
```

have any advantage over this?

```
private int aNumber;

public void assignVal(int aVal){
    aNumber = aVal;
}
```

Comment: No, it is strictly and exactly the same. The difference between the two is a matter of opinion.

Comment: i dont see any performance issue on both.

Comment: `this.` is used to instruct the **COMPILER** only (the bytecode generated is the same) about what you want to address, i upvoted this question since i dont see why it should be -1 its a valid question. the advantage of the first method is that you keep the naming of variables consistent. a common practice is to use a slightly different name like `number` and `Number` just to avoid using `this.number`. its a horrible practice (that I admit to sometimes doing :) ).

Comment: Also I often use `this.` even when it is not needed - it makes the code more readable AND it doesnt create bugs when someone decides to add a parameter that is named the same as a class field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no performance or other obvious advantage for using `this.aNumber` vs. just `aNumber`, other than possibly clarity of to which object instance the `aNumber` belongs. Basically it comes down to preference.

When using just `aNumber`, the `this` prefix is implied.

One possible advantage and a case where using the `this` becomes necessary is when you have a method that has an argument passed to the method that has the exact same name as a class instance variable. In this case, it is necessary to prefix the class instance variable with `this` to 'choose' the right property to access.

For example, if you have a class and method declared as:

```
class ThisExample{
    private int aNumber;

    public void setANumber(int aNumber){
        //Here is is necessary to prefix with 'this' to clarify 
        //access to the class instance property 'aNumber'
        this.aNumber = aNumber; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that you don't have to figure out 2 variable names that refer to one thing. It is slightly more readable, and makes it so your variables are always descriptive of the value.