# Android AlertDialog error during showing

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, floating-action-button

I am working on an android project, at this point, I want to have this 'fab' in such a way that onclick, it brings a pop-up window with a text input. and two buttons.
But it brings an error which I have tried to fix and lastly I thought I can find help here.

This line has an error:

> AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); with this
>   one too: final EditText input = new EditText(this);

```
 private String m_Text = "";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("QuickSearch:");
            //input initial
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            //
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT );
            builder.setView(input);
            // Set of  buttons to be displayed.
            builder.setPositiveButton("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.show();


            //Search action here.
            //Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                  //  .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(yourActivity.this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating new `Alertdialog` instance in each time button click.. without removing the view

try this:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();


  fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            builder.setTitle("QuickSearch:");
            //input initial
            final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            //
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT );
            builder.setView(input);
            // Set of  buttons to be displayed.
            builder.setPositiveButton("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    alert.dismiss();
                }
            });

            alert.show();


            //Search action here.
            //Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                  //  .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `this` is referring to that `onClick` not the `context of that Activity`.

Code should be like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this);
final EditText input = new EditText(YourActivityName.this);
```

- [What is the meaning of “this” in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java)