# Octree StackOverflowError

Tags: java, data-structures, stack-overflow, octree

Good day, I am implementing an Octree. However, I kept receiving a StackOverflowError when having an input size greater than 2. I am clueless on why I am getting this error.

Instantiation of Octree

```
octree = new Octree(3, new Point(0,0,0));
```

where the first parameter is the dimension and the second parameter is the root

Code for the population of the Octree:

```
public void generateList(int num)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < num; i++)
        for (int j = 0 ; j < num; j++)
            for (int z = 0 ; z < num; z++)
                if (!(z == j && j == i))  {
                    octree.add_nodes(i,j,z);
                }
}
```

Code for the add_nodes of the Octree

```
public boolean add_nodes(double x, double y, double z) {

    boolean success = false;
    System.out.println(x+","+y+","+z);
    if (this.i < 8) {
        if (compare(x, y, z)) {
            if (root.childPoints == null) {
                System.out.println("Root is null" + x + " " + y + " " + z);
            }

            this.root.childPoints[i] = new Point(x, y, z);
            this.i++;
            success = true;
        }
    }

    else if (this.childNodes == null) {

        this.create_nodes_of_nodes(x, y, z);

        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            double tempx = this.root.x - root.childPoints[j].x;
            double tempy = this.root.y - root.childPoints[j].y;
            double tempz = this.root.z - root.childPoints[j].z;

            int checker = compareValues(tempx, tempy, tempz);

            this.childNodes[checker].add_nodes(root.childPoints[j].x,
                    root.childPoints[j].y, root.childPoints[j].z);

        }
        root.childPoints = null;

        double tempx = this.root.x - x;
        double tempy = this.root.y - y;
        double tempz = this.root.z - z;
        int checker = compareValues(tempx, tempy, tempz);
        this.childNodes[checker].add_nodes(x, y, z);
        // this.i=0;
    }

    else {

        if (childNodes != null) {
            int checker = compareValues(x, y, z);
            childNodes[checker].add_nodes(x, y, z);

        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal$BinaryToASCIIBuffer.appendTo(FloatingDecimal.java:307)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.appendTo(FloatingDecimal.java:89)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:709)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:226)
at edu.modesta.test.octree.Octree.add_nodes(Octree.java:73)
at edu.modesta.test.octree.Octree.add_nodes(Octree.java:97)
at edu.modesta.test.octree.Octree.add_nodes(Octree.java:107)
at edu.modesta.test.octree.Octree.add_nodes(Octree.java:107)
at edu.modesta.test.octree.Octree.add_nodes(Octree.java:107)
and an additional 400 lines of at 
edu.modesta.test.octree.Octree.add_nodes(Octree.java:107) error
```

Hope someone could answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain because I can't see the rest of the code, but it looks like at some point you entered `add_nodes()` when `i >= 8`. From then on, your control flow says

`if (this.childNodes == null)`, do some stuff then call `add_nodes()`,

`else if (childNodes != null)`, do some stuff then call `add_nodes()`.

Either way, you're calling `add_nodes()` if `i` isn't less than 8, and since you never decrement `i`, each subsequent call is going to call `add_nodes()` too.

Each time you call a method, the new method's frame gets added on the stack. A [`StackOverflowException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror) happens when eventually that stack gets too big. Since you hypothetically call `add_nodes()` infinite times, each call grows the stack a little until it gets too big, hence your Exception.

As an aside: I'm a bit confused why you refer to `childNodes` as `this.childNodes` and also just `childNodes`. `this` is typically only necessary if you have two variables with differing scopes but the same name, which you don't have here. You might want to brush up on [using `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java) as well.