# What is the difference between this(var) and this.var in JAVA

Tags: java

What is the difference between this(var) and this.var in JAVA.?

```
public class Clock {

    private long time = 0;

    private Clock(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public Clock(long time, long timeOffset) {
        this(time);
        this.time += timeOffset;
    }

    public static Clock newClock() {
        return new Clock(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

Comment: this() calls another constructor. `this.` means use the field on `this` object and `var` is a keyword in Java 10. To see when each line of code does I suggest you step through the code in your debugger.

Comment: Check [that answer in the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3728188/4391450) to get a complete set of `this` meaning.

Comment: @PeterLawrey `var` is not a keyword in Java 10, it is a reserved type name (see [JEP-286](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286))

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 4):

Given the class

```
public class Clock
{
    private long time = 0;

    public Clock(long time)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

you use

- `this(x)` to call the constructor with the parameter `x`. This is called [constructor chaining](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-constructor-chaining-with-example/) and you can only call `this()` from a constructor, where it has to be the first statement. Contructors may not call themselves through constructor chaining.
- and you use `this.time = x` to set the member called `time` to the value of `x`. `this` indicates the scope of `time`, e.g. if you are in a method with a local variable `time`, using `time` will get the *closest* scope from the method, which is the local one. If you want the instance scope, you use `this.time`.

---

For further reading, see [Java Language Specs - 8.8.7 Constructor Body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7) and [Java Language Specs - 6.3 Scope of a declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) as well as the following sections.

Comment: Note that `this()` only works from the constructor **as a first statement!!**, it is not allowed inside a method.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't quite sure about that. So it's constructor chaining for every use of `this`.

Comment: Check [JLS 8.8.7. Constructor Body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7) to complete your answer.

Comment: To improved the second explanation. `this.time` allow you to specify the scope. if you are in a method with a local variable `time`, using `time` will get the "closest" scope from the method, which is the local one. If you want the instance scope, you use `this.time`. It become a bit more complex when we are in an inner class... I will not go deeper here ;)

Comment: @AxelH thank you very much for your additions. I just brazenly copied parts of your comment into my answer, I hope that's okay for you. Almost my whole answer is your contribution anyways ;-)

Comment: Nah, that's fine. Your answer was already quite good so there were no point to create my own at this point.

Answer (score 2):

The first one (`this(var)`) calls the constructor with the `var` as parameter, while the second one simply references the `var` property within the object.