# Panel stays open even after I call JPanel.dispose()

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

As opposed to making a JFrame object, I extended JFrame and created a Panel. I want  the panel I created to close when the user clicks certain buttons, but the panel still stays open, even when I put an action listener with the dispose() method. I know my code is a mess right now but if you could please take a look and see what I'm doing wrong.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class StartUp extends JFrame{

    private JButton createAccount, login;
    private static final int WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 300;

    public StartUp(){

        createView();

        setTitle("MovieBase Login");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);

    }

    private void createView(){

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 1;

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcome to MovieBase, your personal Movie Database!");
        panel.add(label, constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 2;
        createAccount = new JButton("Create Account");

        panel.add(createAccount, constraints);

        createAccount.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                new CreateAccount();
            }

        });


        createAccount.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
               dispose();
            }
        });


        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 3;

        login = new JButton("Login");
        panel.add(login, constraints);

        login.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                new Login();
            }

        });

        login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

            }
        });

    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    StartUp window = new StartUp();
                    window.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Seperate Class**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class CreateAccount extends JFrame{

    private JLabel user, pass; //label next to username and password field
    private JTextField username; //enter username
    private JPasswordField password; //enter password
    private JButton create;
    private String u, p;
    private static final int WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 300;

    public CreateAccount(){

        createView();

        setTitle("Create Account");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);


    }

    public void setUser(String usn){
        u = usn;
    }

    public String getUser(){
        return u;
    }

    public void setPass(String psd){
        p = psd;
    }

    public String getPass(){
        return p;
    }


    private void createView(){

        setVisible(true);
        JPanel panelMain = new JPanel(null);
        getContentPane().add(panelMain);

        user = new JLabel("Username: ");
        panelMain.add(user);
        user.setBounds(50, 30, 120, 25);

        username = new JTextField();
        panelMain.add(username);
        username.setBounds(140, 30, 150, 25);


        pass = new JLabel("Password: ");
        panelMain.add(pass);
        pass.setBounds(50, 100, 120, 25);

        password = new JPasswordField();
        panelMain.add(password);
        password.setBounds(140, 100, 150, 25);

        create = new JButton("Create");
        panelMain.add(create);
        create.setBounds(170, 180, 100,25);


        create.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String usn = username.getText();
                String psd = password.getText();
                setUser(usn);
                setPass(psd);
            }


        });

        create.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                new Login2().setVisible(true);
            }

        });

        create.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               dispose();
            }
        });



    }

}
```

Comment: Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). In this case, we'd add both the 'open' panel and another entirely blank panel. On 'close', flip the view to the blank panel.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `dispose` method on `JPanel` - I see you calling it twice, both times on your extensions of `JFrame`.

More specifically - methods in Java are always called on some object with the pattern `object.method(arguments)` - Java provides a shortcut notation - when the object is not specified, [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3728062/836214) is implied. When you call `dispose()`, you're not explicitly providing any object it's being called on, and `this` in that context is your extensions of `JFrame`.

If you just want to hide the panel, you can call [`setVisible(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setVisible(boolean))

Comment: do you know where in the program I would call setVisible(false) ?

Comment: You'd call it in the place you want to hide your panel.  More specifically, you would call `mainPanel.setVisible(false)` or `panel.setVisible(false)` (or whichever is the name of your JPanel object). Side note - I'm confused why all of your buttons have multiple `ActionListener` attached (ie: your `create` button has 3 listeners - this is really the equivalent of having one listener with all the same code in it - is that what you intend?)

Comment: Oh okay thank you. And yes I changed that, haha, I thought I needed separate action listeners but I realized I didn't.