# Using this as a parameter for addfocuslistener method

Tags: java, focus

uQty.addFocusListener(this);

I am working an example from Object Oriented Design in java, and am perplexed about the use of this as a parameter for the addFocusListener method.  I have done an extensive online search for an explanation, but all I get are more examples with no explanation. Does this refer to the field or the object that the field is part of?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of "this" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java)

Comment: Does this refer to the field or the object that the field is part of, as a field(attribute) is based on an object?

Comment: I've added an answer for better formatting

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the instance of the object that it is used in. So when using `uQty.addFocusListener(this)`, it would be in a class that implements `FocusListener`.

For instance (For this example I'm going to assume `uQty` is a `JTextField`):

```
public class Foo() implements FocusListener {
    public Foo() {
        JTextField uQty = new JTextField("A TextField");
        uQty.addFocusListener(this);
    }
}
```

In this example, `this` refers to the class `Foo`, and as the class implements `FocusListener` it can be added to an object as one.

Comment: That's what I thought, but the usage seemed a little ambiguous.