# How do I access external variables in function?

Tags: java

What code should I add to print `"123"`?

```
class people {
    String name = "123";
    String FinalName ;

    void getName() {
        String name = "456";
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Qualify `name` with `this`.

Comment: @ernest_k You could just add this as an answer, I imagine. `this.name`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do getters and setters work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work)

Answer (score 1):

> Within an instance method or a constructor, `this` is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using `this`.
>
> So effectively you use it for multiple things:
>
> - **clarify that you are talking about a field, when there's also something else with the same name as a field**
> - refer to the current object as a whole
> - invoke other constructors of the current class in your constructor

Try this below:

```
class people {
    String name = "123";
    String FinalName ;

    void getName() {
        String name = "456";
        System.out.println(this.name);
    }
}
```

From [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java)