# Difference between this & getClass in Java

Tags: java

Can someone please explain the difference between `this` and `getClass` in Java?
Aren't they the same? `getClass` returns the class of an object and `this` does the same thing, right?

Comment: `this` returns the object itself from inside an instance method.

Comment: Imagine you have a class called Horse and create an Object like `new Horse("Mr. Ed");`. Calling `getClass()` in that object will tell you its a Horse (return Horse.class) while `this` will refer to the specific "Mr. Ed" horse object.

Comment: What makes you think / say they even remotely produce the same thing??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of "this" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java)

Comment: Before anything you should probably familiarize yourself with [difference between a variable, object, and reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32010172)

Comment: "Aren't they the same" you can easily check this by checking `(Object) this == getClass()` (you need the cast to get it to compile) and `this.equals(getClass())`.

Answer (score 2):

### The difference between an object and a class

No, they are pretty different, so much that it doesn’t make much sense to compare them.

- `this` can be regarded as a *constant reference* to the containing *object*. So not a class, and not being a method it *doesn’t return* anything. It just *is* a reference.
- `getClass()` is a method and returns a reference to an object’s *class*. So not the object itself. Also being a method you can trivially call `getClass()` on a different object — any object, in fact — whereas `this` is always *the* containing object.

An example may demonstrate it. The following isn’t meant to be meaningful as a program that anyone could use for an external purpose.

```
package ovv.so.objects.basic;

public class ThisAndGetClassDemo {

    int i;
    
    public void foo() {
        i = 3;
        System.out.println(this);
        System.out.println(getClass());
        System.out.println(this.getClass());
        System.out.println("A string".getClass());
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ThisAndGetClassDemo " + i;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThisAndGetClassDemo().foo();
    }

}
```

Output from the program is:

> ```
> ThisAndGetClassDemo 3
> class ovv.so.objects.basic.ThisAndGetClassDemo
> class ovv.so.objects.basic.ThisAndGetClassDemo
> class java.lang.String
> ```

So you see:

- `this` gives us the object (printing it implicitly calls `toString()` and then prints the return value).
- `getClass()` and `this.getClass()` produce the same output. Calling `getClass()` without qualification (without mentioning which object’s `getClass` method we want to call) calls the object’s own `getClass` method — exactly the same as what `this.getClass()` does. In both cases the class is printed, not the object itself.
- Finally `"A string".getClass()` gives us the `String` class because `"A string"` is an instance (an object) of that class.

I do understand your confusion, though. Every now and then we hear programmers being sloppy and in what they say not making that distinction between an object and a class — in particular in situations where there is only one object of a given class in play (which happens often). It’s like saying “horse” without making explicit whether I mean *the* horse (the object; given there is only one around) or I mean the *concept* of a horse (the class).

Comment: interesting ones to add: `ThisAndGetClassDemo.class` and `getClass().getClass()` :-).

Comment: I agree,@bvdb. Considering the OP is probably a beginner, I think I have broadened the question enough already, so I will leave those as an exercise to the interested reader (who should have an IDE and hence an opportunity to try them out).

Comment: many thanks for the detailed explanation