# What does "this" mean for ViewPagers?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-viewpager

I am making a page listener, I've seen a view people do this:

```
ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

What does that mean? What does that code even do, seems like nothing? I thought "this" meant the current Activity or context but I feel like the above code is not doing anything.

Comment: The current instance of the class you're in.  In this context, the class you're in should be implementing the OnPageChangeListener interface.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of "this" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means it is referring to a onPageChangeListner object which u need to create sepearately. So you will have to create a `OnPageChangeListener` like this:

```
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()  pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {}
```

And then use it like:

```
ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this)
```

So basically this means the reference of the onPageChangeListener object

Comment: Thank you! This answer makes sense!