# What does 'this' do when no instantiated variable follows it? [Java]

Tags: java, instance

I'm not entirely sure how to word the question properly in google without returning this.instanceVar, so any and all help is sincerely appreciated.

```
public class PracticeThis {
    private String str;

    public PracticeThis(){

        //What is "this" referring/doing??

        this("pizza Rulez");

    }

    public PracticeThis(String str){
        this.str = str;
    }

    public void practiceMyThisKnowledge(){
        String str = "Who says pizza rulez?";

        System.out.println(str);
       
        //Not sure how "this" is interacting here;
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
    return "According to practiceThis: " + str;
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of "this" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java)

Answer (score -2):

In `this("pizza Rulez");`, `this(String)` refers to the constructor with one string parameter of this class.

In `System.out.println(this);`, `this` refers to an instance of the `PracticeThis` class.

If you try to print the `PracticeThis` class, java will call the methods `toString()` in the class.

Comment: Not here it doesn't. It refers to another constructor.

Comment: this() vs this are different stuffs. Here this() constructor is being called to call the overloaded constructor. The this keyword is normally used to make reference to the current instance of a class(the object)