# Java: Method with int return type can access private variable, but boolean return type can't?

Tags: java, methods

So there's probably a really obvious answer to this but at the moment I'm very confused.

I started learning Java and am doing the mooc.fi Java Programming course. There's an exercise where I have an Apartment class and I have to make a couple of methods that compare a variable from one object to another (both objects are from the same class).

So I made a boolean return type method with an (Apartment compared) constructor. Then I used this.variable to get the value of the variable of the current object. I made a getter method to be able to get the value of the "compared" object. Then I used compared.getVariable() to get the value of the compared object.

So far so good.

The second methods objective was to return the value difference between the two objects variables. So again, I made a method with an int return type with the same (Apartment compared) constructor. I used the same this.variable for the object. But then instead of using the getter method for the second object, I typed compared.variable. It showed no errors. The program worked.

So I went back to the first method and changed the boolean return type to int return type. and I changed compared.getVariable to compared.variable

Again, no errors.

So why can a method read a private variable of a different object? Why does it work with int but not with boolean?

Here's my code:

```
public class Apartment {

    private int rooms;
    private int squares;
    private int princePerSquare;

    public Apartment(int rooms, int squares, int pricePerSquare) {
        this.rooms = rooms;
        this.squares = squares;
        this.princePerSquare = pricePerSquare;
    }

    public int getSquares() {
        return squares;
    }

    public int getPrincePerSquare() {
        return princePerSquare;
    }

    public boolean largerThan(Apartment compared) {
        if (this.squares > compared.getSquares()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    public int priceDifference(Apartment compared) {
        if ((this.princePerSquare * this.squares) > (compared.princePerSquare * compared.squares)) {
            return (this.princePerSquare * this.squares) - (compared.princePerSquare * compared.squares);
        }
    
        return (compared.princePerSquare * compared.squares) - (this.princePerSquare * this.squares);
    }
}
```

The two relevant methods are LargerThan and PriceDifference

Thanks in advance and sorry if it's a stupid question

Edit: I know it should be pricePerSquare instead of PrincePerSquare but that's how it was pre-written by mooc.fi and I don't wanna change it in case the tester uses PrincePerSquare.

Comment: `private` means private to the _class_, not private to _each object of that class._

Comment: You can read private attribute of another object if its" in the same class as you're actually in, and the return type has NO thing to do with it

Comment: Thanks but why didn't it work in the LargerThan method then? When I try it the error Message says "squares has private access in Apartment"

Comment: what do you mean by "*but boolean return type can't?*" ?? Please post the no-working code and what is not working/error message

Comment: By the way, i really don't get what the "...but boolean return type can't?" part of the question is supposed to mean. What did you try and what error did you get? The access modifiers work the same for each method and field and don't act different depending on data or return types.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3728101/15160601)

Comment: Alright so I tried `if (this.squares > compared.squares)` in the largerThan method. I got the error message "squares has private access in Apartment".
What I meant by boolean return type is, once I changed the largerThan method from `public boolean largerThan` to `public int largerThan` the red lines below .squares disappeared.

Comment: Post the code where you are running this from

Comment: Ok I'm using NetBeans with TMC (Maven) no idea where to check the version. I have screenshots of the code with boolean return and int return:

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/A7uiETV

Comment: Have you tried restarting your IDE or computer, or running a Maven update?  I use Eclipse, but sometimes I get weird errors that aren't real, but Eclipse is messing up

Comment: ALRIGHT it must be a bug with my IDE or something. Because if I change it to int, the code works, like in the image above. but then when I ALT+Z back so it's boolean again, it STILL WORKS. The error is gone. THEN when I delete the .squares and type it in again, the error is back. So weird.

Comment: @Nexevis Yeah I'm betting it's not a real error since when you do change something then alt-z back to the code that was showing the error, the error is gone. But only if you alt-z. If you delete the now errorless code and write it again, the error shows up again. 
I don't want to mess something up by updating since this is the modified NetBeans to be used by the mooc.fi course. It's not a problem I just didn't understand why that error was appearing and it was bugging me.

Comment: @user16320675 is that not allowed? don't know how to upload images internally

Comment: You don't need to tell a story to ask a question. We don't need the build up, the "so far so good", "again no errors". Just show use the code that works, and the code that doesn't work. Tell and why it doesn't work and why you think it should.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make this simple.

```
public class Hide{
    private boolean privy = false;    
    public boolean test( Hide h){
        return h.privy;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Hide a = new Hide();
        Hide b = new Hide();
        System.out.println(a.test(b));   
    }
}
```

That compiles and runs fine. It is a boolean method, that accesses the private member of another instance of the same class. So it seems your error is occurring somewhere else in the build process.

Answer (score -1):

i will try to explainn this refering to the method:

```
public boolean largerThan(Apartment compared) {
        if (this.squares > compared.getSquares()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Inside the main class of Apartment you can have methods that have as parameters variables of the same type of your class, but at runtime they will be different  objects. So you must refer to this object with the appropiate methods.