# Why should main be present in a Java class?

Tags: java

Why should we declare a `main` method? I know that the `main` method is the starting point of the class. But why should only we declare it as `public static void main(String args[])`?

Why can't we declare it as `public static void test(String args[])`? 
Is `main` a key word? How will the JVM know that it will be the starting point?

Comment: The application has to start somewhere, does it? Since the dawn of time (1972?) the `main` has been the way to go, why change it in java?

Comment: @sanbhat The question isn't clearly worded, and I'll edit. The question appears to be about why the method is named `main`, not why it needs to be static.

Comment: It's not a keyword. "How will the JVM know that it's the starting point?" --> by reading its name "main"

Comment: @chrylis the OP asks why the name `main`, which seems to be [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/151666/991778) in the question I have mentioned above

Comment: @sanbhat Sorry, missed down in the second answer.

Answer (score 6):

The JVM has to know somehow where the starting point of your program is. The way the designers chose to mark that is to call the entry method `main`, because the same name is used for that purpose in C (which most programmers were familiar with at the time) and it makes sense. There's nothing particularly magical about the name, they just had to choose something, and that was a practical choice.

Answer (score 3):

When a program begins, it has to begin from somewhere.. Well, this is the `main` method.

---

Why static?

- When the JVM calls the main method, there is *no object* existing for the class being called. So it  has to have *static* method to allow this from class.

Why public?

- The main method is called by the JVM to run the method which is outside the scope of project.

Why void?

- Think about it, once the main method finishes, it doesn't mean that the program finished. If it spawns a new thread it might be that these threads are still running.

Comment: The question as I understood it was about the name `main` rather than the rest of the signature.

Answer (score 1):

there can be a number of methods in your class which can be public and static. How can JVM decide which method is the starting program. TO avoid ambiguity, The Java language decided a particular standard for the method to be executed by JVM. This standard says that "a self executable class should have a method with following signature :

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {  }
```

Here is how this standard help JVM

Public : it allow JVM to access and execute method of your class
static : the method can be executed just by class name(without making object)
void   : returns nothing ( JVM expects nothing from your method)
main   : In order to make your class self executable, the JVM look for this method name and life of your program is valid from the first statement of this method to last statement of this method. as soon as the last statement of this method is executed, your program terminates and instance of JVM dies. This name standard also helps JVM to find a particular entry point. If JVM allow any name then it would be multiple entry points and JVM would get confused. So they decided a single entry point and called it main .

Answer (score 1):

> why should we declare main method? I know that main method is the starting point of the class. But why should only we declare as `public static void main(String args[])`?

Basically, because that is how it is defined.  (And the reason they decided to use "main" rather than some other name is that "main" is the name used for the entry point of a C or C++ program.)

---

> Why can't we declare as public static void test(String args[])?

Because then the JVM wouldn't be able to find the entry point.  Suppose, hypothetically, that the entry point method could be anything.  Now consider this example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void foo(String[] args) { ... }

    public static void bar(String[] args) { ... }
}
```

... and this command line ...

```
$ java Test
```

Which method gets called?  The `foo` method?  The `bar` method?

---

> Is that main key word?

No.  It is just a *well known* method name.  As far as the core Java language is concerned, the `main` method is just a method with a particular signature.  Indeed, you can have *other* `main` methods in the same class with different signatures.

---

> How will JVM knows that it will be the starting point?

Because it is *specified* that the JVM uses a `main` method as the starting point.

---

> Why should main be present in a Java class?

Well ... you don't have to have a `main` method in every class ... or indeed any class ... if you have some other way to launch the JVM that uses a different convention for the entry point.  But otherwise, you need at least one class with a suitable `main` method if you want your application to be runnable.

Answer (score 0):

`It is static` - Compiler need not create an object to enter into the method
`void` - java is platform independent . Hence if it returns something , it may vary from platform to platform

`public` - for access

main() is required so that compiler gets a door to enter into your application . As the name implies , it is the main method that should be executed first .

Answer (score 0):

JVM follows a specification and shares that specification in form JLS with developers. JVM in its specificaton mentions that main method in the following form is the starting point for any standalone java application:

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

From the specs:

Hence as developers we should adhere to the JVM specification so that JVM can understand what we are trying to do.

If my answer is not descriptive or understandable then follow the specification:

> The Java Virtual Machine starts execution by invoking the method main
>   of some specified class, passing it a single argument, which is an
>   array of strings

Read more:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html

Answer (score 0):

You can compile any Java class without a main method, but a standalone application can't run without a **main()** method.

The main method is the method that's defined to be called at the start of an application. Without it, there is no place to start running.