# how to increase the value of the variable

Tags: java

Hi guys i am new new to java i have my home work to be done where i declare the global variable but my variabale is changing .

Program :

```
main()
{

    public static final double j =20;   
    public static final double l =5;

    if (l=5)
    {
        for (; j<=50  ; j+=2)
        {
            System.out.printf("value of j is %d\n",j);
        }

        for (; j>=4; j-=2) // i want here the value j to be 20 ... 
        {
            System.out.printf("value of decrement is %d\n",j);
        }

    }
}
```

its working when i intialze once again j=20 in decreament for loop ... but i want j to start from 20

Comment: If this is Java, then why is it tagged  JavaScript or C++? These are completely different languages.

Comment: Use correct indentation when posting here, makes it much easier to read.

Comment: j=20; before second for

Comment: ya sure i will correct from next time .. thx guys

Comment: @user1121883  ya i mentioned  that it wortks fine when i intialize it on decreemtn for loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with , there is nothing called **Global Variable** in JAVA.
Plus you have so many compilation errors in the code:
I will list out some:

1. return type of `main()` function is missing.

   `void main() 
      { 
        //code here
      }`
2. static and public modifiers are not for local variables(method variables)

   `public static final double j =20; // this is wrong inside a method.`

   **Reason:** Inside the methods variables have local scope. There is no public/private scope for method variables.
   So it should be :

   `final double j =20; //final means 'j' behaves as a constant`
3. You are trying to assign 5 to l inside if :

   `if (l=5)` // it will not compile because first l will become 5 and inside if the expression should be boolean.
   it should be `if(l==5)`.
4. `for (; j<=50  ; j+=2)` will not compile because j is declared as a final variable.

Fix can be : `for (int jNew=0;jNew<=50;jNew++)`

**So the overall code can be :**

```
void main()
{
      final double j =20; 

      final double l =5;


    if (l==5)
    {
    for (int j3=0; j3<=50  ; j3+=2)
    {
        System.out.println(j);

    }
    for (int j4=0; j4>=4; j4-=2) // i want here the value j to be 20 ... 

    {
        System.out.println(j);

    }


}
}
```

Go through the basics of [Java here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply declare the variable in with the loop itself

```
for(j=20; j>=4; j-=2) // i want here the value j to be 20 ... 
{
   System.out.printf("value of decrement is %d\n",j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to the question itself but please have in mind that in Java main method should be declared like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
```

Reason for that can be found here: 
[Why is the Java main method static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146576/why-is-the-java-main-method-static)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an unexpected value (52) for j is the statement `j+=2`.

On each iteration, this overwrites the value of j with the incremented value.

After a few iterations of the loop, the value of j becomes 52 which causes the loop to exit since the condition `j<=50` isn't satisfied.

Hence, before the start of the second loop, you need to reinitialize j with the value 20.

Note:

If you want i & j to be public static, declare them outside the method but within the class.

Since you do not need decimal numbers, use `int` instead of `double` .