# How to use scanner in java?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;  

public class Initials {  
    Scanner getin = new Scanner (System.in);  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        String Name;  
        System.out.println("Enter your name's Initials::");  
        Name=getin.nexlinet();  
    }  
}
```

error : non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context?

Comment: Either make getin static or make it a local variable in main method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `Scanner` objects doesn't hava a method called `nexlinet`, I guess you want `nextLine()` instead.

About the error, you can't reference a `non-static` variable from a `static` method (in this case, that method is `main`).

**Why?** Because `static` variables can be used even if no instances of the class have been created.

**How to solve it?**

- You can declare the variable `getin` as `static`:

  ```
  static Scanner getin = new Scanner(System.in);
  ```
- Or you can create an instance of the class and access to the instance field `getin`:

  ```
  Initials some_name = new Initials();
  // ...
  name = t.getin.nextLine();
  ```

**Notes:**

- Try to follow Java naming conventions. Use `'mixedCase'` for methods/variables and use `'CamelCase'` for classes/interfaces.
- I'd recommend you to read about access modifiers. Why? Look at the second solving way. The class `Initials` should provide a *getter/setter* method for the instance field `getin`, so you don't have full access on it. Also, it's a good practice to declare instance fields as `private` (and use *getters/setters*).

Comment: Thnx, I now understand what my mistake was. Either I could declare the variable static or make the "main" as non-static.

Comment: @Hunter the [`main()` method is a *very special* method, it should always be `public static void main(String[] args)`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146576/why-is-the-java-main-method-static)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
// ur code
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner getin = new Scanner (System.in); // <-- move scanner declaration inside main
        Name=getin.nextLine();  // <-- note this change also
// ur code
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create scanner class object inside main method.

because outside declared non static variable cant accessed into static methods.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{  
    Scanner getin = new Scanner (System.in);  
    String Name;  
    System.out.println("Enter your name's Initials::");  
    Name=getin.nextLine();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not aware of static and non-static variables or methods.

1. static variable or method can be accessed any where whether it is static or non-static method.
2. non-static method or variable cannot be accessed in static methods.

so modified code should be :

```
import java.util.Scanner;  

public class Initials {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        Scanner getin = new Scanner (System.in);    
        System.out.println("Enter your name's Initials: ");  
        String Name = getin.nextLine();  
    }  
}
```

otherwise modify Scanner to`static Scanner getin = new Scanner (System.in);`

Answer (score 0):

Static methods:
    Cannot access non static variables.
    Cannot invoke non static methods.
    Cannot use "this" keyword.
    Cannot use "super" keyword.
    Cannot override static methods.
so you can't access non static objects inside of the main method because its a static method.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;  

public class Initials 
{  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
   {  
        Scanner getin = new Scanner (System.in);  

        String Name;  
        System.out.println("Enter your name's Initials::");  
        Name=getin.nexlinet();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code to be more educative.

Comment: Sure why not,I have created the scanner object inside the main static method. If we create this outside the main method then it will not be assessable in the main method because a non static variable can not access in the static method and finally it will produce an error. After creating the Scanner object I am taking the input from user by using scanner's object and finally I am saving it in another variable

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Initials {

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
     Scanner getin = new Scanner (System.in);  
    String Name;  
    System.out.println("Enter your name's Initials::");  
    Name=getin.next();  
}
```

}