# How to write a Hello World application in Java?

Tags: java

I have been trying to make the Hello World Java application. But when I try to run the program it says that my selection has no main type. Here is my source code.

```
public class HelloWorldClass {

    System.out.println("Hello world!");
}
```

Comment: What does your book or tutorial say about it being necessary to have a `public static main` method?

Comment: Also your code doesn't even compile :)

Answer (score 3):

Because it has no `main()` method where the code would take the starting point. Use this

```
public class HelloWorldClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!"); 
  }
}
```

Please note there are some of the things you should always take a note of while programming. Which is also known as the **syntax of the language**.

Java requires you to have the class written as the FileName, `HelloWorldClass` is the name of the file of yours.

Then, any data type of it. In my case it is `void` which means it won't return anything to you in the end.

Also, you should write `String[] args` which is the Parameter to the method. I was last night trying to understand why I should write these? There is a method, which runs without these, but Java recommends you to add the  parameters.

Comment: main method cannot be instantated..What does that mean? IMO we instantiate class only not methods.

Comment: :Also how will you run main method without String[]args ??

Comment: @P.K普 It is just required to remove the ambiguity while running the main function. So, it removes any changes of adding a `new main()` :) I think you get it, if don't http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146576/why-is-the-java-main-method-static...Without that, the compiler would give the error, of writing the main method as`public static void main(String[] args) {...` I tried is last night hehehe :)

Comment: You cannot instantiate a method... you can however invoke it.

Comment: @RymanHolmes, so that caused a downvote? :) Right?

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Nope... I didn't downvote, You're answer was correct

Answer (score 2):

When running Java you need a main method so the compiler knows what to run:

```
public class HelloWorldClass {

 public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("Hello world!");
        }

}
```