# Why the main method should be in static

Tags: java

The following code gives error because i am not put static keyword to main method. Please explain why main method not working without static keyword.

```
public class Test {
public void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        int a = new Integer(10);
        System.out.println(a);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

`Error:`Main method is not static in class Test, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: Because there is not class instance from which the JVM can call the `main` method.  It's a requirement of the language, why should it be anything else?

Comment: Because it makes no sense to put a "entry" function at instance level. Also, It will be present when a class is loaded. The JVM doesn't need an instance of `Test` to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since main method is `static` `Java virtual Machine` can call it without creating any `instance` of class which contains main method.

If main method were not declared static than `JVM` has to create instance of `main Class` and since constructor can be overloaded and can have arguments there would not be any certain and consistent way for `JVM` to find main method in Java.

also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146576/why-is-the-java-main-method-static) for detailed and very well explained answers.