# Is it possible to run java program without static

Tags: java, static

When we tried  to run the following program then it successfully runs.

```
class with {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("With static");
    }
}
```

but even if we tried to run the following program it did't ran successfully.

```
class without {
    public void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("With static");
    }
}
```

we know becuase in this program we have't use `static` in `main()` method. So, we want to ask that the : - is it possible to run java program without static ? if is it possible then how can i do this.

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146576/why-is-the-java-main-method-static

Comment: It is possible if you start your programm via the scripting engine.

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible.

### Why?

The first method (`main`) needs to be `static`, i.e **context-free**.

You cannot start your program with already instanciated objects, variables, etc...

Comment: what is mean by  `instanciated objects`

Answer (score 0):

No.

To run without static, you'd first have to have an object to invoke that method from (using new). Where would you put the instruction to create that object? In a non-static method? That needs an object to invoke that from... Where would you put the instruction to create that object? In a non-static method? That needs an object to invoke that from... Where would you put the instruction to create that object? In a non-static method? That needs an object to invoke that from...