# Nothing happens with this code. Why?

Tags: java

```
public void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

This compiles in my environment, but nothing happens at run time.

Comment: Please show the full class, and how you're executing it. If that's all there is, I'd expect an exception due to the VM not finding a *static* `main` method to launch.

Comment: Please Look at the accepted answer of this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146576/why-is-the-java-main-method-static

Comment: Thanks all for the quick replies. This solved my problem. What a pesky little error.

Answer (score 3):

If should be a static method, otherwise it can't serve as the entry point of a Java application.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
       ------
{
    System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The main method should be : `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: `public`, `static` and `void` are not part of the signature :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void main(String[] args)
```

change this to

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 1):

`main()` method syntax is,

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

you are missing `static`, so `JVM` not able to find your `main()` method i.e. entry point so there is noting happened.

Check your console It should display error message as

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
Exception in thread "main"
```