# I am a java beginner. Why the main in java starts with Static keyword

Tags: java, static, program-entry-point

```
 class Student{
    public **static** void main (String[]arg){
    }
    }
```

Here why we are using static keyword to start a main method.
From my knowledge I can say

> Static will get memory and it can retain its value
>   Is that only reason for using Static key work in main.
>   Explain in detail thanks

.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146576/why-is-the-java-main-method-static check this link

Comment: Note that the meaning of `static` in Java is different from the multiple meanings that it has in C and C++. In particular, "Static will get memory and it can retain its value" - this is not what `static` means in Java.

Comment: My question is why the compiler searches for static initially followed my void and main to start a program.