# What is the use of object in Java?

Tags: java

For example if we wrote one program like

```
class sum{ 
    public static void main(String []k){
        int a=10,b=30,c; c=a+b; 
        System.out.println("op is"+c);
    }
}
```

in this program where is object?

Comment: `System` is a `Class` (which extends from `Object`), `System.out` is an `Object`, you class extends from `Object`, all objects inherit from `Object` if you don't otherwise implicitly extend from another `Object`. `Object` also defines `hashcode` and `equals` (and other base methods) which are all very useful

Comment: k is an object (a string array); System.out is an object (a PrintStream); "op is" is an object (a string literal)...

Comment: @MadProgrammer `System` is a class, not an object.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish And I thought I was nit picky :P

Comment: OBJECT SYNTAX IS LIKE FOR EX:class objname=new classname() but in the above format we cannot use this type of syntax then where is object

Answer (score 1):

also when we run any java program there is one object internally created. object of java.lang.Class.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have multiple objects !

When you will run your program, `sum` is the first one. You also have an array of strings `String []k`

`System` is also an object with a field `out` which is of type `PrintStream``

`"op is"+c` is also an object of type String

PS : note that a, b and c are primitive types. More about data types in java : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: in memory (RAM) ! Have a look at : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model

Comment: It loads the class into the memory. That doesn't mean that `sum` will be instantiated. Why do you think `main` is `static`? So it doesn't need to create an instance of the surrounding class (which wouldn't work if there aren't any non-parameterized constructors).

Comment: Actually you raise a good point : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146576/why-is-the-java-main-method-static

Comment: how we see java libraries using cmd prompt

Answer (score 0):

"op is" is a String object
k is an array of String objects