# where spring defines variable value, which is referred by some xml file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean

I am trying to understand from where does the value of a variable comes from, when it is referred in Spring xml file.

For example:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/${com.example.deploy.environment}/com.example.config/mysql.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="false" />
```

Where is the value of com.example.deploy.environment defined? In my project I searched all over, however i couldn't find anywhere where this values is defined.

Any information in understanding this would be of great help.

Comment: Q: In a spring.xml file, where does the value of a variable comes from?  A: It's important to recognize that it can be several different *kinds* of "variable" (including - but not limited to, simple Java "System.Property" values), and can be defined - or overriden - in several different places.  Look at the links Sanjay Rawat cited.  Be sure to "upvote" and "accept" his answer if you found it helpful.  Also: what about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35933597) question you asked a few days ago?

Comment: PS: If you're running your Spring app from an IDE (like Eclipse), you'd probably add `-Dcom.example.deploy.environment=abcxyz` to your Arguments > VM arguments tab.  Similarly, if you were running on TomCat or an App server like WebSphere, you'd also probably define your arguments with a "-D" in the JVM settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This value can come from a variety of source:

1. application.properties file which you can define in `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean.

   ```
   <bean id="mailProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
       <property name="location" value="classpath:application.properties" />
   </bean>

   ...
   //Inside application.properties
   com.example.deploy.environment=prod
   ```
2. You can provide via command-line:

   With Maven vm arguments for JVM System property:

   ```
   mvn package -Dcom.example.deploy.environment=prod
   ```

   Running Spring Boot Application:

   ```
   java -jar app.jar --com.example.deploy.environment="prod"
   ```

   3. From System Environment variable of the Operating System. You might have to restart after setting environment variable. See below for windows:

[image: In Windows]

Refer this [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) and this [article](http://www.summa.com/blog/2009/04/20/6-tips-for-managing-property-files-with-spring) for more info.