# java filename reference compile error

Tags: java, reference, filenames

```
package concurrencyTest;

public class concurrencyTest implements Runnable
{    
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         concurrencyTest c = new concurrencyTest();
         Thread t = new Thread(c);
         t.start();
     }
}
```

Hi, I'm just trying to get my java concurrency test to run. But I'm getting this error :

> Error: Main method not found in class concurrencytest.ConcurrencyTest, please
>   define the main method as:
>   public static void main(String[] args)
>   or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

I'm guessing that somewhere, in the myriad of project directories and subfiles that a java program needs to run, the name of the project or class has been wrongly referenced in lowercase letters. I've manually been thru all the files I can find that span from the root directory and renamed any instance of lowercase 'concurrencytest'. But still it seems the compiler finds a reference to lowercase concurrencytest and so refuses to compile. Any idea where this reference may be?

My root directory, source directory, and java code file are all called 'concurrencyTest'

**edit**
 amended the original code for this question to include 'static' in the main method definition. Doing this was necessary but has not fixed the problem.

Comment: `public void main` are you sure the error should not be interpreted literally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the Java main method static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146576/why-is-the-java-main-method-static)

Comment: The error messages states *... please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args) ...*. Comparing it to your main method signature points out that your one is not `static`. Just make it `static` and the error loses its origin.

Comment: Please define the main method as: public **static** void main(String[] args)

Comment: Looks like netbeans thinks your package is called `concurrencytest` with a lowercase `t`. In other news, conventions about naming things are there for a reason. Don't try to fight them unless you know what you are doing and have a good reason to.

Comment: The class that you posted is called `concurrencyTest.concurrencyTest` and that is how you need to capitalize it to invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote the `main` definition wrong. You should change it as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, I've now added the static keyword to the main method. But the compile error described in the OP remains.

Comment: @gristy How are you running this?

Comment: I'm using netbeans 8.2 IDE, compiling it with F6

Answer (score 0):

I found a reference to 'concurrencytest' in the meta file ...\concurrencyTest\nbproject\project.properties
So I changed it to 'concurrencyTest'

Also when NetBeans can't find the expected main method in the class it expects, it opens a 'RunProject' window where it lists main methods from classes it has found. For me it found a main in 'concurrencyTest' so I selected it.

One of these actions solved the problem, but not sure which one.