# I don't know how to fix this error the code compiles but doesn't run properly

Tags: java

So the code will compile but when i try to run the code i get this error.

```
    public class Die
{
  private int randomValue;

  public Die()
  {
    randomValue = ((int)(Math.random() * 100)%6 + 1);
  }
    public int getValue()
    {
      return randomValue;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Error: Main method not found in class Die, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java every application must have a main method, which is the entry execution.

In this case i supposed you want to create an object of Die class and then print the random generated value, for this make it the next way:

Create a main method in the class:

```
public class Die{

    private int randomValue;

    public Die(){
        this.randomValue = ((int)(Math.random() * 100)%6 + 1);
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return this.randomValue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //Create a new object of Die class
        Die dieObject = new Die();

        //Print random value ussing getter method
        System.out.println("The random value is: " + dieObject.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All Java programs require a `static` method named `main` in order to start. With a quick google search you can find tons of links like [this one.](https://www.journaldev.com/12552/public-static-void-main-string-args-java-main-method) However, your class can be compiled since it has no compile errors but it cannot run because there is no `main` method.

In your case I guess you want to do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] arguments)
{
    Die die = new Die();
}
```

Also a nice-to-read is [Why is the Java main method static.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146576/why-is-the-java-main-method-static)