# Why is a static method called main launchable?

Tags: java, jvm, program-entry-point, launch

I guess there's something about jvm.BUT how does jvm recognize it?For the name main,or the static property?

That's my little confusion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the Java main method static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146576/why-is-the-java-main-method-static)

Comment: That seems at most to partially answer the question, TBH.

Comment: Not really.I 'm clear about these modifier words.I'm just confused about how jvm work with their combination into a launchable entrance.

Comment: The JVM doesn’t do anything about it. The execution starts with the `main` method, because the `java` command you’re using to start your program is searching for that method and calling it.

Answer (score 1):

When JVM runs an application by specifying a class, it will look for the main method with the signature of `public static void main(String[])`.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; Neither having a `main` method nor a `static` method is sufficient, and the method needs to be both, as specified by the Java Language Specifications (JLS).

If there is something about the JVM then it is usually specified in the Java Language Specifications. In this case it is [section 12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1) which specifies the requirements for a main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

or

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

So instead of just being *static* it also needs to be public and have a `void` return type (integer makes more sense maybe, but Java is multithreaded, so the return value is given using `System.exit(int)`). Furthermore, it must accept `String` arguments, as you would expect.

Note that the `main` method has been designed to be used in a CLI environment such as the command line in Windows or one of the many shells in Linux / Unix / MacOS. It is similar to the C/C++ `main` method; Java was based on the C/C++ language.

I've also checked this against Java 18, and the text is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Java main method is the entry point of any java program. Its syntax is always `public static void main(String[] args)`.

When java runtime starts, there is no object of the class present. That’s why the main method has to be static so that JVM can load the class into memory and call the main method. If the main method won’t be static, JVM would not be able to call it because there is no object of the class is present

You can find a detailed explanation [here](https://www.journaldev.com/12552/public-static-void-main-string-args-java-main-method).

Comment: but why is the name of main method fixed....i mean ,i'm literally clear about the public and static property.I just cant understand why is "main"?And if it's a tradition about  C something,how does it work?I know nothing about C,sorry

Comment: In Java "main" is not a keyword but JVM looks for the "main" method when it starts executing a Java program. The signature of the main method needs to be in a specific way for the JVM to recognize that method as its entry point.

Comment: Yes,thank you so much!That's the point.What specific way?