# Calling a method with parameters from main method properly

Tags: java

I am in my first week of programming Java and am finding the syntax and errors extremely confusing. I am expected to write the code for the following inputs/output:

> Access: public
>
> Name: evaluateFormula
>
> Return: double
>
> Parameters: 2
>
> integer values - valA and valB
>
> Body: Evaluate formula and return value - (valA + (valB mod 20) * 3.14 / 12)

I have tried:

```
public class Area
{

    public void evaluateFormula(int valA, int valB) {
        System.out.println(valA + (valB % 20) * 3.14 / 12);
   }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        evaluateFormula(1,2);
    }
}
```

I am getting the error :

> Area.java:14: error: non-static method evaluateFormula(int,int) cannot
> be referenced from a static context
> evaluateFormula(1,2);
> ^ 1 error

Being our first week, we haven't learned what static even means, or why we should be using it in the main method. How do I get this code to run properly with 1 week worth of Java knowledge?

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ has given a good example to you already, for the reason why the main method have to be static, you can check it here: [Why is the Java main method static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146576/why-is-the-java-main-method-static)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option 1:
you do the method static

```
public static void evaluateFormula(int valA, int valB) {
```

or

option 2:

you create an instance of class Area and call the method in main(...)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    Area a = new Area();
    a.evaluateFormula(1,2);
}
```